react-photo-album doesn't work with renderToStaticMarkup
There is some issue with ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup, with the below code it renders the main container i.e react-photo-album--rows but its empty, images are not rendered
ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<PhotoAlbum
  photos={photos}
  {...config}
/>);

But when I add defaultContainerWidth it renders the image inside
<PhotoAlbum
  ...
  defaultContainerWidth={300}
/>

What I tried to solve:
I redered the component with below check, if mounted===true then only the component will render, esle it wont. But it didnt solve either
const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setMounted(true)
}, []);


This is the expected and well-documented behavior.

To enable server-side rendering, specify the defaultContainerWidth prop. Otherwise, React Photo Album produces an empty markup on the server and renders on the client only after hydration.

https://react-photo-album.com/#HowItWorks_SSR
